# add a new frame to the tree

Tags: ros, frame, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I use the following commands to build add a frame to a tree. The rviz shows there is a frame, but when I try
obj_frame_pose_stamped = change_pose_stamped_frame(self.tf_listener, pose_stamped, "base_link"),
the error is:tf.Exception: Frame id /grasp_frame does not exist!

Do you have any ideas?

```
        br = tf.TransformBroadcaster()
        br.sendTransform((1,0,0),
                         (0, 0, 0, 1),
                         self.object_stamp[0],
                         "grasp_frame",
                         "openni_rgb_optical_frame")
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10470/add-a-new-frame-to-the-tree/) by [Nutan](https://answers.ros.org/users/170/nutan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2011-07-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to publish the transform on a regular interval. TF has a buffer is only a couple seconds deep. If you publish the transform and then try to lookup the transform between that frame and another frame more than the time range of the TF buffer you will not be able to. In rviz you will most likely see the frame turn grey after some time interval showing that the transform information is stale.

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nutan](https://answers.ros.org/users/170/nutan/) on 2011-07-04**:
it works. Thanks!